# Why doesn't the volatile keyword work as expected in java code?

Tags: java, volatile

I'm learning concurrency knowledge in Java. About volatile keyword, it should make variable visible in different threads. But in my demo code, it doesn't seem to work as expected. The method `run()` in the class which implements `Runnable` will never stop.

```java
public class VisibilityDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TimeConsumingTask timeConsumingTask = new TimeConsumingTask();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new TimeConsumingTask());
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    timeConsumingTask.cancel();
  }
}

class TimeConsumingTask implements Runnable {
  private volatile boolean toCancel = false;

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (! toCancel) {
      System.out.println("executing...");
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    if (toCancel) {
      System.out.println("Task was canceled.");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Task done.");
    }
  }

  public void cancel() {
    toCancel = true;
    System.out.println(this + " canceled.");
  }
}
```

Comment: `timeConsumingTask` is never started.

Comment: "About volatile keyword, it should make variable visible in different threads.": No, volatile means that this variable isn't read from cache, but from main memory instead.

Comment: @gkhaos - It is more complicated than that.

Comment: @StephenC indeed, volatile-qualified variables are no target of compiler optimization (anything else?). My point was that "volatile" does not specify anything about accessibility (like private or public)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main method you have two instances of your task:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TimeConsumingTask timeConsumingTask = new TimeConsumingTask(); //<-- one
    Thread thread = new Thread(new TimeConsumingTask()); //<-- two
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    timeConsumingTask.cancel(); //<-- cancel() on first 
  }
}
```

You're passing one to the `Thread` constructor and then call `cancel` on the other one. You need to call `cancel` on the instance passed to `Thread`, like so:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    TimeConsumingTask timeConsumingTask = new TimeConsumingTask(); 
    Thread thread = new Thread(timeConsumingTask); //<-- difference here
    thread.start();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    timeConsumingTask.cancel();
  }
}
```